# Why is the output order different from the call order when using fprintf with stdout or stderr?

Tags: c++, printf, stdout, stderr

My environment is Debian GNU/Linux 11.

The `fprintf` function with param `stdout` or `stderr` gives unexpected output order.

```
int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    fprintf(stderr, "22222\n");
    fprintf(stdout, "111\n");
    printf("3333 \n");
    printf("44444 \n");
    return 0;
}
```

I've run this many times and got many different results:

```
//①
22222
Hello, World!
111
3333 
44444

//②
Hello, World!
111
3333 
44444 
22222
```

What's the reason?
Or, I want to understand the phenomenon, what knowledge do I need?

On my understanding, the output log should like this:

```
//③
Hello, World!
22222
111
3333 
44444
```

About the two output logs of ①/②, I don't understand.

I think log ③ is right, but it does not appear, that makes me wonder.

Comment: what do you mean by `the code only output like ② , but appear ①`? And there's no C/C++ language. `std::cout` doesn't exist in C

Comment: Neat, but a great example of why you should not cross the streams. Even when fighting Gozer.

Comment: You notice that the “22222” is the only thing out of order, right? That is because you are printing that to a _different_ output stream than everything else, and there is no requirement that the two print in the same order as your output. Also notice that everything else is always in order? That is because `std::cout` is by default “tied” to the C standard output stream. If you break that connection, you may get even more random orderings. Chances are the reason has to do with when the streams get _flushed_.

Comment: If you want a specific order, make sure to flush the stream at the important points. Better yet, don’t mix output methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output is **never** like ② because [output to `stderr` isn't buffered](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/std_streams) so `22222` will be flushed immediately and would be before any other numbers. Output to `stdout` may be *line-buffered* (default on Linux) or *full-buffered* (default on Windows)

The output shouldn't be like ① either because [you're already flushing with `std::endl` in the first line](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl), hence `Hello, World!` would be printed first. That's why never use `std::endl` unless you really know what it's doing. Always use `std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";`. See ["std::endl" vs "\n"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/213907/995714)

③ should be the correct output because on Linux it'll flush on every statement, and on Windows the final 3 writes to `stdout` are flushed at once at the end

```
Hello, World!
22222
111
3333 
44444
```

If there are any differences then there are some issues with your stdlib

By default [the legacy and C++ streams are also synchronized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/sync_with_stdio) so it's possible to mix both types of streams with some performance penalty. You can disable it like this

```
std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
```

to get better performance but now the `Hello, World!` string can be printed anywhere

Comment: @Tom what's cline? And you don't run g++ to get that output, you just use it to compile the program and then run the program

Comment: 1. I use g++ compile main.cpp , and got a.out file , and then i run a.out got log ③ .
2. CLion is IDE ,  I use CLion run many times got output ① and ②
3. sorry i made a typo .

Comment: *"to get better performance ... "* in a a program making tens or hundreds or thousands of outputs... Good point to make, but very relative to use of I/O in the individual program. Not a scintilla of difference here.